# Syntax error, File "program.py", line 13 def calc_stats('data.csv'): please help me I am trying to open csv file in python for a course

Tags: python, numpy, function, syntax

```
import numpy as np

def calc_stats('data.csv'):
  data = np.loadtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',')
 
  mean = np.mean(data)
  median = np.median(data)

  return np.round(mean, 1), np.round(median, 1)
calc_stats('data.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You define a function with parameter names, not the data itself. Change to a parameter name that you use in the function and now the "data.csv" used to call the function is the name that is used.

```
import numpy as np

def calc_stats(filename):
  data = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=',')
 
  mean = np.mean(data)
  median = np.median(data)

  return np.round(mean, 1), np.round(median, 1)
calc_stats('data.csv')
```